# Undo SVN remove from depo

Tags: svn

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What’s a simple way to undelete a file in subversion?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/497670/whats-a-simple-way-to-undelete-a-file-in-subversion)

I wanted to import a new project called **prj1** into the depo. Inside **prj1** there is **sub1**, **sub2**, ...

```
cd prj1    
svn import prj1 http://someurl.com/project/branches/
```

But this was the wrong path and I should have added **prj1** at the end of the above line, so I intended to remove the sub-projects in prj1 and I intended to do:

```
svn remove http://someurl.com/project/branches/sub1
```

But I mistakenly did:

```
svn remove http://someurl.com/project/branches
```

As a result **branches** is gone. Inside **branches**, in parallel to **prj1**, there are some other projects that I don't have local copy of (haven't checked them out). I was wondering if there is any way to undo the accidental svn remove of **branches** and bring it back to the depo.

**EDIT:**

As suggested by Lekensteyn, Lazy Badger, and https://stackoverflow.com/a/3128696/1383356, I solved the problem by checking out the latest version (102), and rolled back to version 100 (which was before import) using svn merge. Here are the details:

```
svn co http://someurl.com/project
cd project
svn merge -r 102:100 http://someurl.com/project
svn commit -m "Rolling back to the old days of r100 :)"
```

Comment: @Lekensteyn: That question seems to be about undoing the removal of a file from your local directory. My question is about removing a folder from the depo without having a local copy of other projects. The SVN documentation here distinguishes between the two: http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.6/svn.ref.svn.c.delete.html

Comment: I cannot directly think of a SVN command that does that on the local side, but if you have server-side access, http://stackoverflow.com/q/402159/427545 might be of help.

Comment: I don't have server-side access

Comment: Any reason why you cannot checkout /project and use `svn merge` to get back to the previous version? See the linked question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your import and remove are separate revisions in repository (*check it* with `svn log`)

Undoing of any commit in SVN is a job of reverse-merge: you have to know revision ID of commit with remove, checkout affected path (`http://someurl.com/project/` - yes, may be **giant checkout**, but it's your troubles), backmerge bad revision and commit undoing revision into repo

Another way is checkout `http://someurl.com/project/branches/` at the latest revision, when it exist (use PEG-syntax), branch it, update to HEAD, merge branch (restoring tree really), check results in WC, commit