# Revert back to previous version

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn

I am using Tortoise SVN. I made a mistake and committed the files(Revision 6). I want to revert back to revision 5 and commit the files again. How can I do it???

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I revert the Subversion repository, not my working copy, to a specific revision?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3128659/how-do-i-revert-the-subversion-repository-not-my-working-copy-to-a-specific-re)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Go to "SVN Show log", right click on the offending revision and select "Revert changes from this revision". Your working copy will look as before. You can then commit to definitively undo the changes, or make valid changes before.

Answer (score 0):

Hi If it is on your local desktop you should be able to right click - tortoiseSVN - revert. This should show past versions. Try

http://tortoisesvn.net/docs/release/TortoiseSVN_en/tsvn-howto-rollback.html